# Какое разрешение браузерной игры выбрать для десктопов

Tags: кроссбраузерность, разрешение

Начал делать браузерную игру, ориентированную на десктопы и ноутбуки и никак не могу определиться с разрешением игры. Хочется чтобы она охватывала как можно больше устройств, но также при этом была как можно больше и учитывала разные менюшки в браузерах, чтобы не было прокруток. Помогите с выбором разрешения!

p.s. делать буду в canvas

Comment: Мне кажется, лучший вариант - сделать "резиновый" рендер, чтобы не зависеть от разрешения экрана

Comment: Резиновый не катит, у меня будет сетка в игре, да и canvas не растянешь, там все по пикселям

Comment: Ну, вообще full hd, как минимум, я думаю. Уже в 2003м у меня на 5" телефоне было такое разрешение.

Comment: FullHD на телефоне это не то, у iPhoneX реальное разрешение 375х812

Comment: Гм... Был об айфонах лучшего мнения... Значит просто возьмите разрешение самого "малопиксельного" устройства :)

Comment: Ничто не мешает установить размеры canvas в соответствии с размером экрана и сдвинуть все рисуемые координаты пикселей на нужную величину. Делайте резиновый рендер и не морочьте голову.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот нашел статистику, думаю сделать разрешение игры 1200х700

Comment: Лучше делайте резиновый рендер.

Comment: А если будет 4k монитор, что из моей резиновой игры выйдет? Тяжело контролировать дизайн при таком разбросе разрешений

Comment: Отмасштабируйте свою игру под 4k, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: @ValeriyPetukhov для ретин и 4к мониторов есть devicePixelRatio